# Display a grid over a blurry background image, and on click of a square in grid change to non blurry background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have been trying to create a grid over a blurry background image which when clicked displays the non-blurry background image.

So far I have been able to display a grid over a blurry background image. The squares within the grid have a hover effect on them which changes their opacity. What I need it to do now is on click of any of the squares, the non-blurry version of the background image is shown, but only within the chosen square. Is this even possible with css? Your help would be greatly appreciated.

The below is the link to where you can see the project. You might need to click load script if you are using chrome.

https://www.theppcpresents.com/test/new/index.html

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Link seems to be a single div with an inline image (not a bg image) which does not seem to fit the description given above. Where are the grid divs?

Comment: Hi Paulie, thanks for your response. I've created the grid in jQuery using colomns and rows. I know exactly what I need to achieve, but maybe have done it the wrong way to begin with.

Comment: Pretty sure, barring some really complicated markup that this is going to be impossible. However, until we can see a fully functional grid in JSFiddle we can't help further. Background images can't be unblurred unless you swap out another image,

Comment: I have used this js fiddle for the grid. The only thing is, I need the grey overlay to be an image and then another image sitting behind it which will swap out once someone clicks on the square. http://jsfiddle.net/MvFx9/

Comment: What I need is the grid to be over a blurry version of an image, and then once someone clicks on a square, the non blurry version of the image shows within that square.